# Why are none of my form's controls being recognized as being ComboBoxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, combobox, event-handling

I'm making a combobox "readonly" in this way:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // for this to work, set the comboboxes' Tag to its SelectedIndex after setting that
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
     int validSelection = Convert.ToInt32(cb.Tag);
    if (cb.SelectedIndex != validSelection )
    {
        cb.SelectedIndex = validSelection;
    } 
}
```

...and then trying to set all of the comboboxes on the form to that handler like this:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is ComboBox)
    {
        (c as ComboBox).SelectedValueChanged += comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
    }
}
```

...but the if condition is never equating to true; there are several ComboBoxes on the form...???

Comment: Are they inside a panel? Put a breakpoint in there by the way.

Comment: I see now that since most of my controls are on a panel, I have to check foreach control in this.panel1.Controls. Is there a way to check ALL of the controls on the form, without having to specify the parent? - Yep, Silvermind, you were right (I didn't see your comment until I added this one and it refreshed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ComboBoxes are most likely inside other panels.

Try going through them recursively:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ChangeCombos(this);
}

private void ChangeCombos(Control parent) {
  foreach (Control c in parent.Controls) {
    if (c.Controls.Count > 0) {
      ChangeCombos(c);
    } else if (c is ComboBox) {
      (c as ComboBox).SelectedValueChanged += comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

step though it set a breakpoint on the begin { and call c.gettype()

also you might want to do this

```
if( c.gettype() == typeof(ComboBox))
{

}
```